# Automatically indent R to match function spacing

Tags: r, vertical-alignment, indentation, auto-indent

I've been searching everywhere for an answer to this question but haven't come up with any solid answers. I'm wondering if there is a way to have multiple lines of code within a function auto-indented to match the spacing of the function above. This is within RStudio.

Here's what I currently have:

```
mutate(
  n_analyses = n(),
  sd = sd(slope, na.rm = TRUE),
  mean = mean(slope, na.rm = TRUE)
)
```

And this is the spacing I'd like to have performed automatically:

```
mutate(
       n_analyses = n(),
       sd = sd(slope, na.rm = TRUE),
       mean = mean(slope, na.rm = TRUE)
      )
```

Is there a setting that makes this happen that I can't seem to find, or do people just indent the first line within a function manually and then auto-vertically align the remaining lines?

Comment: @Bankelal I found formatR to be pretty inconsistent with what I was hoping to achieve. It moves the text to begin on the same line as the function, and only takes an arbitrary number of spaces. I think ctrl + shift + A works better, but still doesn't always solve my original question. I'll admit I'm being a little particular about my code formatting, but I'd like to keep it as readable as possible.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think I've got it now. Ensuring that "Vertically align arguments in auto-indent" is checked (in global options >> code >> editing) will make sure that this occurs, but ONLY IF you leave the first bit of text (i.e. n_analyses = n(),) on the first line along with 'mutate('. While I visually prefer the code to start on a different line, I can work with this. If anyone does have a solution though I'd love to hear it.